# For each loop works, but iterator does not

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach, iterator

Write a method `counts` that accepts a `List` of integers and a `Set` of integers as parameters, and returns a map from each value in the set to the number of occurrences of that value in the list.

My solution #1:

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> counts(List<Integer> list, Set<Integer> set) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();

    for(Integer element : set) {
        int count = 0;
        for(Integer sub : list) {
            if(sub == element) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        map.put(element, count);
    }

    return map;
}
```

My solution #2:

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> counts(List<Integer> list, Set<Integer> set) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator();

    for(Integer element : set) {
        int count = 0;
        while(i.hasNext()) {
            if(i.next() == element) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        map.put(element, count);
    }

    return map;
}
```

Input:

```
list: [4, -2, 3, 9, 4, 17, 5, 29, 14, 87, 4, -2, 100]
set: [-2, 4, 29]
```

Expected output:

```
{-2=2, 4=3, 29=1}
```

Output for #1:

```
{-2=2, 4=3, 29=1}
```

Output for #2:

```
{-2=0, 4=3, 29=0}
```

The first one works, but the second one does not. Why? They are essentially the same thing, or am I missing anything? Also, would using a `for` loop work to traverse through the list? If not, why?

Comment: What do the different methods do or not do, what is your expected output?

Comment: Are you sure you want to compare by reference?

Comment: In one case your iterator is impicitly declared inside the outer loop, in the other case it is explicitly declared outside...

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but there's a better way to do it: Iterate through the List and for each element in the list you update your map if the set contains that element. (You would have to check for `null` values, or initialize your `Map` with `for( Integer i : set ) map.put( i, 0 );`

Comment: @Danyel Thanks for the suggestion, but I fail to understand how/why this solution is better?

Comment: In your example, you iterate through your "small" set once and for every element you iterate through the *whole* list. that's `O(s*l)` at all times. With my solution, you iterate **once** through the list, and for each element in the list you only need to iterate over the set until you find **one** occurrence of the current element. Plus, lists are usually longer than sets, so that's another benefit.

Comment: Ah.. makes sense. Thanks for filling me in. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forget to reset the iterator after each loop, try the following:

```
for(Integer element : set) {
    int count = 0;
    i = list.iterator(); // resets the iterator to the first element. 
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        if(i.next() == element) {
            count++;
        }
    } // by the end of this loop the iterator has no next elements, need to reset.
    map.put(element, count);
}
```